# NodeJS req.body empty in funtion nodejs - Rest API whit ExpressJs and sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using ExpressJS and sequelize. I need invoke two functions ("accoun.js" and "people.js") into a main function (fullaccount.js) receving data in "fullaccount.js" for submit and process in the others functions, I received ready req.body in "fullaccount.js"  but in "accoun.js" and "people.js" REQ.BODY IS EMPTY

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');

var app= express(); 
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 4094); 
app.use(morgan('dev')); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false})); 
app.use(express.json());        
app.use(require('./routes/back/account.route'));
app.use(require('./routes/back/people.route'));
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Working in port: '+app.get('port'));
});
```

fullaccount.js

```
const account=require( './account.ctrl');
const people= require ('./people.ctrl');
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export function add(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); //-> it's ready. RETURNING JSON
  const {nick,pass,email,firstNam,lastName,identCard,birthDate,genderId,countryId}=req.body;

  account.add({nick,pass,email},res); //=>> invoke add method from account controller return undefined
  people.add({firstName,lastName,identCard,birthDate,genderId,countryId},res); //=>> invoke add method from people controller return undefined
}
```

account.js

```
import Account from '../../db/models/account.mdl';

export function add(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); // it's return undefined 
};
```

people.js

```
import People from '../../db/models/people.mdl'; 

export function add(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); // it's return undefined  
};
```

I don't know what the error is, I need help

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.body` is `undefined` because you are not passing the initial `request` to `account.add` or `people.add`

For example, for account, you are actually passing an object that contains `nick`, `pass` and `email`

```js
account.add({nick, pass, email}, res); // req.nick, req.pass, req.email are available
```

To avoid confusion, you should rename the `req` parameter in `account.add` to `data`. Good names will save you a lot of headaches. :)

Comment: Hello, I made this change in account.js:  function add(req,res) => add(data,res) but data.body is still undefined.

Comment: just `console.log(req)`, not `req.body`, you will see what I meant